# Retreive Other Games' Data From Game Center API

Tags: ios, game-center

Is there a way to retreive data, like the time the user played the game, title of the games and so on, from IOS game center for the games the user played before? Assuming those games supports game center. Thanks!!

Comment: I don't think you could access other games' data from game center api event those support game center.

Comment: @kubrickG thanks for the answering. For my understanding, those popular mobile games like Candy Crush Saga do not offering APIs as well right? I tried to look around but cant find them.